# Overlay audio with video in XCode

Tags: ios, audio, video, avmutablecomposition

Can anyone help me merge 2 videos and an audio file?

Below is the code from Ray Wanderlich. It helps me combine the 2 videos, one after the other. Then, it lets one add audio. However, when it adds the audio from the audio file, it removes any audio present in any of the combined videos.

So, what I really want is -

1. combining the videos, one after the other
2. adding / overlaying the music with the audio file
3. also, retaining the audio that is present in any of the videos

For example, if in the video file 1, I am saying "Hello, how are you?" and in the second video file, I say "I am doing fine" with jazz music in the audio file, I want the final video to have jazz music playing along with "Hello, how are you?" and "I am doing fine" being heard in the final video.

So, in short, I want to combine 2 videos and overlay the audios in the video files with that in the audio files.

Below is the code I have.

Please can someone help?

Ray Wanderlich's code:

```
- (IBAction)MergeAndSave:(id)sender{
if(firstAsset !=nil && secondAsset!=nil){
    [ActivityView startAnimating];
    //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    //VIDEO TRACK
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];

    //AUDIO TRACK
    if(audioAsset!=nil){
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration)) ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


    } 

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration));

    //FIXING ORIENTATION//
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)   {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0) {FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
    CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;
    if(isFirstAssetPortrait_){
        FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
        CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }else{
        CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }
    [FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:firstAsset.duration];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *SecondlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:secondTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *SecondAssetTrack = [[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation SecondAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL  isSecondAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform secondTransform = SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == 1.0 && secondTransform.c == -1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == -1.0 && secondTransform.c == 1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(secondTransform.a == 1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == 1.0)   {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(secondTransform.a == -1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == -1.0) {SecondAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
    CGFloat SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/SecondAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;
    if(isSecondAssetPortrait_){
        SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/SecondAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
        CGAffineTransform SecondAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio,SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [SecondlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform, SecondAssetScaleFactor) atTime:firstAsset.duration];
    }else{
        ;
        CGAffineTransform SecondAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio,SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [SecondlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform, SecondAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:firstAsset.duration];
    }


    MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,SecondlayerInstruction,nil];;

    AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
         });
     }];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code:

```
AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];
```

then you can use **preferredVolume** property of **AVMutableCompositionTrack** to chande audioTrack volume.

Good luck